# Using multiple training files in libsvm

Tags: svm, libsvm

I am trying to train a binary classifier using libsvm.
My data quantity is very large and I need to know of any way I can divide the input data into different files and input to the train function.

So basically I know this :
svm-train train file

I wonder if there's a way to do:
svm-train train_file1 train_file2 train_file3.....

Does anyone know any way to do this??

Comment: you already suggest a solution by splitting the file. what is the initial problem? file system? training time? time for metatraining (grid.py)?

Comment: @stefan Can't split the files and input them to the library as far as I know and want a way to give the library all the split files as input.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FAQ's](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f414) of libsvm

> For large problems, please specify enough cache size (i.e., -m). You may train only a subset of the data. You can use the program subset.py in the directory "tools" to obtain a random subset.

Comment: thanks I had read through the faq, and this is not the solution I was looking for. I can't compromise with the amount of data I feed

Comment: basically, I have to use it all

Comment: @MonsieurBeilto Did you try using -m ? for large data, libsvm generally crashes because of no memory. By using -m you can specify the code to allocate more cache size. The rule of thumb is you need to set -m equal to 3 times the size of your dataset. ie if your data is 500 mb, you'll have to set -m to 1500. Also note, that not all systems can allocate 1500 mb and might continue to crash so try different values of -m (1000, 1500, 2000..).  And hopefully it'll work.